# How do I find people who actually want to play Left 4 Dead survival mode on Xbox live

Tags: xbox-network, left-4-dead

It seems like about 50% of the time I join a random game of Survival mode on XBox Live I end up with a bunch of 12 year olds who think it's funny to just go around and shoot each other. If I really want to play survival mode how do I find a game where people actually want to play instead of just dick around?

Comment: Get it on the PC?

Answer (score 2):

I think by searching for player's name that are serious and invite them into your server could be the only way to have what you want.

Search in forums or other gaming website about L4D and you should fine players older than 12. Add their name in your friend list in the Xbox and you're set.

Answer (score 1):

Ask reddit /r/gaming, or some folks on here and other forum sites for an online meetup.

Or just lobby jump until you find some good players.... good luck though.